# jsf 2 dynamic dialog which loads new content after clicking "next"

Tags: jsf, dynamic, dialog, scope

I need your help about a step-by-step prozess in jsf.

I have a database with a table of texts.
All i want is, to show the user in a modal dialog one text with a "all ok" and "errors included" radio button and a "next" button, which updates the DB (inserts a "OK" or "NOTOK" in the DB) and loads the next text passage into the dialog until it is done.

The bean looks like this:

```
LinkedList<StringID> texts = loadTextsFromDB();
```

where StringID has a **String text** and a **int id** variable. So i want to show the user the first StringID in a modal dialog (so that he can't to anything else) and let him chose "ok" or "notok" before he can click "next" which loads the next StringID into the dialog.

Can i do this with modal dialogs? Another problem is that i don' know how to chose the right scopes of the bean... can anyone help me out with some code?

Comment: This is easier if you use a JSF UI component library such as PrimeFaces, RichFaces or ICEfaces as they offer dialogs in single components without the need to write quite some HTML/CSS/JS code boilerplate. Are you using or considering any of them? If so, which version exactly?

Comment: Hi, yes i am using Primefaces. but i don't know how to show StringID after StringID with a "next" button who updates the databse. du you have a source-snipplet?